# I would like to add a google base layer to my openlayers map but it load correctly

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2

This is my script at the top of my HTML file

```
<script src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false">
</script>
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="map.js"></script>
```

This is my .js

```
var map;
function initMap() {
//initialise variables
 var osmlayer;
 var trackloca2;
 var bmenatrack2;
 var pits3;
 var boundary3;
 var track2;
 var pits2;
 var boundaryline;
 var gmap;
//create new map object
map = new OpenLayers.Map("mymap");
 //create new OSM base layer
 osmlayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("Open Street Map");
 gmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
    "Google Streets",
    {numZoomLevels: 20}
    );
```

I have added gmap to the addlayers at the bottom but when I switch from the open street map to the google layer all I am getting is a white screen with my geoserver layers showing,

Comment: Wow, thanks for tidying this all up, I was just in a panic yesterday to try and get it up so it might get answered. Am I missing something simple as to why it wont show the Google base layer also?

Comment: Just an aside, the latest version of OpenLayers is v4.2.0. If you don't already have a large codebase, you might consider switching versions.